# When using jquery ajax with data that contains array, getting the parameter name with [] in the end

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
            url:"SomeURL",
            data: {                
                fields : ["field1", "field2"],                
            },
            success: function(data) {
            }
});
```

Getting this in the server:

```
name = fields[] , VALUE = field1
name = fields[] , VALUE = field2
```

(note the brackets)

Is that a bug? (This starting to happen after I upgraded to 1.5)

Thanx

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question - Where in the "server" are you seeing that? and what is processing the AJAX request?

Comment: The server is tomcat apache and the "Getting this in the server" part represent the name and value of the parameters that are send with the requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug, the serialization changed (but already in jQuery 1.4). Have a look at the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option:

> **traditional** *Boolean*
>   Set this to `true` if you wish to use the traditional style of [param serialization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param).

And from [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) (also have a look at the example):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `$.param()` method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Comment: I already looked at the traditional option and still I'm getting the brackets in the end of the parameter's name. Do you know of a way of getting the parameter name without brackets?

Comment: I just rechecked my code and it turns out I put the traditional in the wrong place. So thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Is there a way to also set `traditional` when using `getJSON()` rather than `ajax()`?

Comment: @hippietrail: As the last sentence in the quoted documentation says, you can set `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`. Or instead of passing the object directly to `getJSON`, you can pass the result of `$.param(obj, true)`.